# Windows logon using Google Authenticator

Tags: windows, login, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Do you know if there is a free (or even better, open source) implementation of the Windows login screen to use with Google Authenticator or any time based authenticator.

It would be a great/cheap way to add 2 factor authentication to Windows.

Comment: not free so not an answer but for ~$30: http://www.rohos.com/2013/02/google-authenticator-windows-login/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, I've found [pGina](http://pgina.org/) which is an open source, pluggable, open source credential provider for windows. But there is no Google Authenticator plugin for it.

There is also [mOTP-cp](https://code.google.com/p/multi-one-time-password--credential-provider/) and [OpenOTP-cp](https://code.google.com/p/open-one-time-password--credential-provider/). I didn't test them, but they seem to do exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Update: mOTP is now here https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp